# Date of Recent RAM Upgrade (Optiplex 745 w/ XP Pro SP3)

Tags: windows, windows-xp, memory

Is there a way to find the date/time of a recent RAM upgrade?

Would that be in any system, bios, or windows log files?  Do any common programs automatically adjust setting upon seeing a new amount of system memory?  Any other thoughts for clues as to when the upgrade occurred?

OS: Windows XP Pro SP3
Computer: Dell Optiplex 745

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're running an automated monitoring system for assets that poll system configs, I don't know of anything that records it. You might get lucky and have error messages logged in the BIOS that would tell you when a memory change occurred.

Comment: Confirming, the BIOS should have a log event about it.  I believe there's a tool to view/clear those log messages without rebooting for Dells, but if not, the BIOS setup screen accessible on bootup should have the option for which you're looking.